# What do the lines starting with # symbol in g++ -E generated translation unit

Tags: c++, g++, translation-unit

I tried to check the translation unit generated for a simple hello world program looks like.
So, I wrote below code in test.cpp.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout<<"Hello World"<<endl;
}
```

I then compiled the above file with g++ with -E option and output the data to a temp file.
The file has c++ code with lines in between starting with # symbols.

Something like below,

```
# 1 "test.cpp"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 1 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "test.cpp"
# 1 "/usr/include/c++/8/iostream" 1 3
# 36 "/usr/include/c++/8/iostream" 3
```

1. What do these lines mean ?
2. Is there any document that I should read or do I have to get knowledge in any specific subject to understand this file?

Comment: Line started with # is a preprocessor directive, like `#include` and `#ifdef` etc

Comment: "Is there any document that I should read" I would start with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor

Comment: @Slava, the translation unit is generated after preprocessing, so those aren't preprocessor directives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/comopts.html

> **-E**
>
> Stop after the preprocessing stage; do not run the compiler proper. The output is in the form of preprocessed source code, which
>   is sent to the standard output.
>
> Input files which don't require preprocessing are ignored.

Then you can find ["Preprocessor Output" in gcc documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Preprocessor-Output.html#Preprocessor-Output):

> ```
> # linenum filename flags
> ```
>
> These are called linemarkers. They are inserted as needed into the
>   output (but never within a string or character constant). They mean
>   that the following line originated in file filename at line linenum.
>   filename will never contain any non-printing characters; they are
>   replaced with octal escape sequences.
>
> After the file name comes zero or more flags, which are ‘1’, ‘2’, ‘3’,
>   or ‘4’. If there are multiple flags, spaces separate them. Here is
>   what the flags mean:
>
> - ‘1’ This indicates the start of a new file.
> - ‘2’ This indicates returning to a file (after having included another file).
> - ‘3’ This indicates that the following text comes from a system header file, so certain warnings should be suppressed.
> - ‘4’ This indicates that the following text should be treated as being wrapped in an implicit extern "C" block.

Answer (score 0):

Line number information.

If you compile the preprocessed output, those can.be used to find the line numbers and files of the original source.